# Cannot add my class in the QList

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qlist

I have my custom class that delivered from QObject:

```
class Client : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    friend class Server;
public:
    Client(QTcpSocket *socket, QObject *parent = 0);
private:
    QTcpSocket *mSocket;
};
```

And try to add it in the my list (QList)

```
auto socket = mServer->nextPendingConnection();
Client client(socket);
mClients.append(client);
```

It outputs next:

> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:521: required from
>   'void QList::append(const T&) [with T = Client]'
>   
> ...
>   
> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:372: error: use of
>   deleted function 'Client::Client(const Client&)'
>        if (QTypeInfo::isLarge || QTypeInfo::isStatic) n->v = new T(t);

How I can add my object in the list correctly?

Comment: Is it all code of Client class? It is strange, since there is no deleted copy constructor and no members that have no copy constructor.

Comment: Yes, it's all code at this moment. Of course, it  has realization in .cpp file for prototypes.

Comment: Can I not use copy constructor and just move object in list?

Comment: QObject’s shouldn’t be copied, make it a list of smart pointers (shared_ptrs/QSharedPointers for example), instead.

Answer (score 6):

[QObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) has private copy constructor and assignment operator. You should store list of smart pointers, instead of objects.

You should not define copy constructor for class, that is derived from `QObject`.

> Instances of subclasses of QObject should not be thought of as values
> that can be copied or assigned, but as unique identities. This means
> that when you create your own subclass of QObject (director or
> indirect), you should not give it a copy constructor or an assignment
> operator.
>
> No Copy Constructor or Assignment Operator
>
> QObject has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment operator.
> This is by design. Actually, they are declared, but in a private
> section with the macro Q_DISABLE_COPY(). In fact, all Qt classes
> derived from QObject (direct or indirect) use this macro to declare
> their copy constructor and assignment operator to be private.

Comment: @Jeka no, there is no rvalue-reference overloads of `append` and another functions in QList as I can see in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use copying of QObject based classes. Use pointers:

```
QList<Client*> mClients;
Client* cln = new Client( socket );
mClients << cln;
....
```

Or you can use smart pointers

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know about this way

Comment: @ghostman do not forget to delete object created with new operator. Also using correct using parentness is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should define the `copy constructor` for your `Client` class, it is deleted because of a [valid reason](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) and it looks like the `QList` wants it.

Comment: User defined constructor doesn't mean that copy constructor will be deleted.

Comment: It’s deleted because QObjects delete it, for good reason: It makes little sense to copy a QObject (signal/slot connection semantics would break). QObjects cannot be sensibly used as value types, so one should create them on the heap and manage them e.g. as shared pointers (`QList<QSharedPointer<Client>>`). Or reconsider if the class needs to inherit from QObject at all.

Comment: I used so: `auto client = QSharedPointer<Client>(new Client(socket));` Is it correct?